# c# cancel thread gracefully – why so long

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

Recently I was studying [the fantastic guide to galaxy of multi threading by Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). 
I've found one thing I can't explain: after setting up the cancellation variable it takes a lot of time (in terms of time of execution of other pieces) to execute the last loop.
I've tried volatile approach, also locker object and MemoryBarier calls, result is always the same

```
class Program
{
    static ReaderWriterLockSlim _rw = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    static List<int> _items = new List<int>();
    static Random _rand = new Random();
    static /*volatile*/ bool _cancel = false;
    static object _cancelLock = new object();

    static void Main()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(Read); t1.Start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(Read); t2.Start();
        Thread t3 = new Thread(Read); t3.Start();

        Thread t4 = new Thread(Write); t4.Start("A");
        Thread t5 = new Thread(Write); t5.Start("B");

        System.Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelling... " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff"));
        _cancel = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff"));


    }

    static void Read()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _rw.EnterReadLock();
            foreach (int i in _items) Thread.Sleep(10);
            _rw.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    static void Write(object threadID)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_cancel)
              break;

            int newNumber = GetRandNum(100);
            _rw.EnterWriteLock();
            _items.Add(newNumber);
            _rw.ExitWriteLock();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + threadID + " added " + newNumber+" at "+DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff"));
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    static int GetRandNum(int max) { lock (_rand) return _rand.Next(max); }
}
```

Please see the output:

```
Thread B added 37 at 01:52:20.2916  
Thread B added 64 at 01:52:20.2916  
Thread B added 89 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread B added 92 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread B added 55 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread B added 60 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread B added 0 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 74 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 90 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 86 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 91 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 19 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 67 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 52 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 73 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 39 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread A added 24 at 01:52:20.2926  
Thread B added 0 at 01:52:20.2926  
cCancelling... 01:52:23.0229  
Cancelled 01:52:23.0229  
Thread A added 93 at 01:52:26.0542  
Thread B added 83 at 01:52:26.0542
```

What I would expect is, that either there is nothing more after the Cancelled Line or there are lines executed quicker, something like at 1:52:23.02**40**

(The results above are when the program was run directly from Command prompt, when ran from within Visual Studio, the "gap" is smaller, but still almost 0,5 second).

Comment: Sidenote: you could achieve the same result using a ConcurrentQueue<T> instead of a List<T>, eliminating the need for locks.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a *threading race*, a classic bug in threaded code.  Your program is also suffering from a problem called *contention*.

Contention first, you can easily tell from the rate at which the program produces output that the Write() method has a very hard time acquiring a write lock.  That's because you've got 3 threads reading and they each only release the read lock for a *very* short time, a nanosecond at best, while they iterate the loop.  This isn't enough to give the Write() method a decent shot at acquiring the write lock, it needs help from the Windows thread scheduler to get a shot at it at all.  Which gives threads that are blocked too long (seconds) a priority boost to give them a chance.

This contention pretty much ensures that the writing threads are both stalled on the EnterWriteLock() call.  Which is *after* the _cancel check.  They'll eventually acquire the lock and perform one more write.

Comment: Hans, thanks! Inspired by your explanation, I've added another logging before the line _rw.EnterWriteLock(); in Write method. And this shows, that in fact there is a similar gap between getting the lock and adding number as between cancellation and the last lines. So - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`CancellationToken` classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx)

You can implement it in place of your `_cancel` variable.

Also, consider using .Net's [thread safe collection classes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) In this case instead of using `List<T>` use the `ConcurrentBag<T>` class.